# How can I edit Bootstrap5 [where can I find SCSS _grid.scss ?]?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm trying to edit one web-portal that deployed on **Bootstrap 5** , but I need to edit one section. And to edit that section I have to find and edit **_grid.scss**, but where's it located? In Bootstrap 5 folder there are no .scss files.

All what want is to edit or find **_grid.scss**

or edit width: 25%; to **width: 20%;**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is to override the `.col-lg-3` width property.
You can either do it directly:

```
.col-lg-3 {
    width: 20% !important;
}
```

or by using a proper css class on the section you want to edit so you want touch all the `col-lg-3` on the page.

Comment: Overriding core layout classes isn't a good idea. There are better, more maintainable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved my question myself. Instead of

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 align-items-stretch mb-5 mb-lg-0">
```

I wrote `col-` 5 times

```
<div class="col">
```

and all my columns immediately  stood on one line and automatically get a properly box-size
[image]

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your original question (which was [XY](https://xyproblem.info). Please revise your original post to ask something that this solution resolves, or delete your post.